# Is there a way to look at photos by date taken in iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app

In Windows Live Photo Gallery, there's an easy way to view photos by date taken:

[image]

How do I accomplish the same thing in iPhoto '11?

Answer (score 3):

Using the search functionality is usually the best way to find unknown options.

First select `Photos` from the sidebar. Then sort by date.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What I've done is created smart albums and organized them by year, then by month. You can create smart albums by going to `File>New Smart Album`. Then, select a date range. 
IMO, this is the best way to do it. I've organized it exactly like your picture.

[image: smart album]

Comment: So you created each year then 12 months per year by hand?  That seems like a lot of work.  I was looking for something out of the box.  But thanks, I'll keep this in mind if I can't find an easier way.

Comment: Yes, I did, but it isn't a terrible lot of work if you duplicate albums. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! If you're in Events, you can go to the View menu, hover on Sort Events and check the By Date option. This will do the same thing for Photos if you're selected on Photos. This will sort the Events or Photos you're looking at by date taken. As you're scrolling though them, a HUD will show the month they were taken.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a whole year's worth of smart albums like @daviesgeek has, and you have Keyboard Maestro installed, you can use a macro I created to change a set of twelve Smart Albums to represent a different year. The instructions and macro file are available [here](http://baconti.me/automate-month-based-smart-album-creation-in-iphoto/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.